# Does a .NET library for the W3C Markup Validator API exist?

Tags: .net, api, soap, w3c, w3c-validation

I'd like to validate that users of my WPF application are putting proper XHTML into its TextBox control.

I found that there's an [API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html) for the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

It's web page says:

> Building of libraries used to interact
>   with the validator's API is
>   encouraged. …

and it lists known Perl, PHP/PEAR and ColdFusion libraries.

Does anyone know of a .NET library for the W3C Markup Validator API?  Does one already exist?

Answer (score 5):

This API is SOAP based. If you want to use it in a .net application you can just add the web reference and code against it. Seems simple enough as it's basically a one-method API...

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615132/how-might-i-use-the-w3c-markup-validator-api-in-my-net-application

Comment: I could use a little help parsing the response:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616817/how-do-i-extract-data-from-an-xml-file-with-visual-basic

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just wrote one: [.NET Wrapper for W3C Validator API](https://github.com/trullock/MuonKit.W3cValidationClient)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of how to your API? I checked it and found it is too complex for me to figure out what needs to be done to call it. Thanks.